# API documentation still accurate?

Tags: api, labor, documentation

My students and I are trying to access child labour statistics data from the Sweat and Toil dataset, with the endpoints as described on https://developer.dol.gov/others/sweat-and-toil/, and using the format as described at https://developer.dol.gov/beginners-guide/#apiv2.

When trying (in Python) to do so with code like the following:

```
response = requests.get("https://data.dol.gov/SweatToilAllStatistics", headers={'X-API-KEY': 'KEYREMOVED'})
```

we get a 404. For some other data sets in Sweat and Toil (and other v2 datasets we've tried), we get a 403 with the following response:

```
{
    "status": "",
    "error": "Invalid API Key"
}
```

But when I use this exact same API key on some v1 API datasets, e.g.,

```
response = requests.get("http://api.dol.gov/V1/DOLAgency/Agencies/?KEY=KEYREMOVED")
```

it works fine, so I actually don't think "Invalid API Key" is the true issue here. The same issue occurs when attempting this with `curl`. Any help anyone might be able to offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: For the first one, I think you're missing a `/get/`: https://data.dol.gov/get/SweatToilAllStatistics gives me an invalid API key (because I don't have one), but not a 404 file not found.